# Why is my Run64BitRuntime flag ignored

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis, 32bit-64bit, sql-server-data-tools

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with SQL Server 2012 Data Tools installed.  For some unexplained reason, my workstation will only run my SSIS code in 32 bit mode.  Here is a dummy data flow I built for testing purposes:

[image]

Here are my settings:

[image]

It only runs `DTSDebugHost.exe *32`.

[image]

I am at my wits end trying to figure this one out.  What do I do to figure out why it is not running just `DTSDebugHost.exe` (the 64 bit version)?

Comment: Weird, Checked the rights? Disabled the setting and enabled again? And you verified that the 64-bit version is in your path?

Comment: I'm admin on the machine.  Yes, I have installed the 64 bit version, and run it to verify that it is 64 bit.  I will check the path tomorrow morning - however, logically thinking, since the 32bit and 64bit exe's have the same name, I would think that a fully resolved path would have to be stored in the registry somewhere, right?

Comment: The path wasn't set in the proper order, but changing the order did not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because VS 2012 is checking to see if VS 2010 ULTIMATE is installed. It just looks for a registry entry.

Solution:

1. Open Regedit
2. Browse to
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\11.0\`
3. Create a Key called `premium`
4. Create a Key called `ultimate`
5. Browse to
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\10.0\`
6. Create a Key called `premium`
7. Create a Key called `ultimate`

Restart VS 2012.

Now it should work in 64-bit mode when you debug.

Comment: You are a superstar. I am using VS2017 enterprise. I created the keys for 14.0 and 15.0. Now it works perfect. Previously vs was crashing because of dtsdebughost.exe x32

Comment: I also had to retarget the Project Properties for SQL 2014. Apparently you can target different versions of SQL, so make sure that matches up with your path order.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into an almost identical problem and solution with SQL Server 2014 Enterprise, after installing SSDT-BI for VS 2013.

> On a side note, I tried using the 64-bit debug host in SSDT-BI VS 2013 on two separate installs. One
>   where a full instance of SQL Server 2014 Enterprise was already
>   installed (with 64-bit debug host installed and verified) and another
>   where no previous SQL Server components had been installed at all. I
>   wanted to ensure that the "no debug with 64-bit runtime" issue was not
>   simply due to a missing 64-bit debug host or that the 64-bit host was
>   not installed as part of SSDT-BI for VS 2013 (It is not. It's part of
>   the full SQL Server itself, Integration Services (Shared Feature).

Per [this thread on Social MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/b6012976-d60f-4ad6-a96d-d181b21ea03a/cannot-debug-ssis-packages-in-64-bit-mode?forum=sqlintegrationservices), adding the following registry key was what got the 64-bit debug host working for me:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\11.0\professional
```